# How can I prevent sqlalchemy from prefixing the column names of a CTE?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Consider the following query codified via SQLAlchemy.

```
# Create a CTE that performs a join and gets some values
x_cte = session.query(SomeTable.col1
                     ,OtherTable.col5
                     ) \
               .select_from(SomeTable) \
               .join(OtherTable, SomeTable.col2 == OtherTable.col3)
               .filter(OtherTable.col6 == 34)
               .cte(name='x')

# Create a subquery that splits the CTE based on the value of col1
# and computes the quartile for positive col1 and assigns a dummy
# "quartile" for negative and zero col1
subquery = session.query(x_cte
                        ,literal('-1', sqlalchemy.INTEGER).label('quartile')
                        ) \
                  .filter(x_cte.col1 <= 0)
                  .union_all(session.query(x_cte
                                          ,sqlalchemy.func.ntile(4).over(order_by=x_cte.col1).label('quartile')
                                          )
                                    .filter(x_cte.col1 > 0)
                            ) \
               .subquery()

# Compute some aggregate values for each quartile
result = session.query(sqlalchemy.func.avg(subquery.columns.x_col1)
                      ,sqlalchemy.func.avg(subquery.columns.x_col5)
                      ,subquery.columns.x_quartile
                      ) \
                .group_by(subquery.columns.x_quartile) \
                .all()
```

Sorry for the length, but this is similar to my real query. In my real code, I've given a more descriptive name to my CTE, and my CTE has far more columns for which I must compute the average. (It's also actually a weighted average weighted by a column in the CTE.)

The real "problem" is purely one of trying to keep my code more clear and shorter. (Yes, I know. This query is already a monster and hard to read, but the client insists on this data being available.) Notice that in the final query, I must refer to my columns as `subquery.columns.x_[column name]`; this is because SQLAlchemy is prefixing my column name with the CTE name. I would just like for SQLAlchemy to leave off my CTE's name when generating column names, but since I have many columns, I would prefer not to list them individually in my subquery. Leaving off the CTE name would make my column names (which are long enough on their own) shorter and slightly more readable; I can guarantee that the columns are unique. How can I do this?

Using Python 2.7.3 with SQLAlchemy 0.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

you're not being too specific what "x_" is here, but if that's the final result, use label() to give the result columns whatever name you want:

```
row = session.query(func.avg(foo).label('foo_avg'), func.avg(bar).label('bar_avg')).first()
foo_avg = row['foo_avg']  # indexed access
bar_avg = row.bar_avg     # attribute access
```

Edit: I'm not able to reproduce the "x_" here.  Here's a test:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    x = Column(Integer)
    y = Column(Integer)

s = Session()

subq = s.query(A).cte(name='x')

subq2 = s.query(subq, (subq.c.x + subq.c.y)).filter(A.x == subq.c.x).subquery()

print s.query(A).join(subq2, A.id == subq2.c.id).\
        filter(subq2.c.x == A.x, subq2.c.y == A.y)
```

above, you can see I can refer to `subq2.c.<colname>` without issue, there is no "x" prepended.  If you can please specify SQLAlchemy version information and fill out your example fully, I can run it as is in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry. I'm talking about in code, when I'm writing the final query. E.g., `subquery.columns.x_quartile`. I'll modify the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if when defining `subq2`, you add another column to the result set? E.g., `s.query(subq, (subq.c.x + subq.c.y))`. I also added version info to my question.

Comment: edited, yeah there's no problem there.  There *are* things that make SQLAlchemy append table names to column names though, and there's ways to deal with that, but I'm not seeing it in the code snippets you've illustrated (unless I had something I could actually run).